# Laravel cannot declare class because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel, class

Following [this](https://tighten.co/blog/tidy-up-your-tests-with-class-based-model-factories) blog post I successfully implemented Class-based factories in Laravel.

Initially I put my `ModelFactory`s in `app/some/folder`. Everything was totally fine. But I want them in `database/factories/classbased`, and then this error started;

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Factories\ClassBased\GroupFactory, because the name is already in use in ..root/project/database/factories/classbased/GroupFactory.php on line 18
```

I have had a good look on SOF and elsewhere about this error, but all the answers seem to be about different reasons/ I can't transpose the answers given to my situation.

I have tried renaming my classes to something totally unique (as `ModelFactory` is already a naming format used by Laravel for its standard factories) but I still got the same error. My custom classes seem to be re-declaring and I don't know why.

This is what I have for my custom class:

```php
<?php
// database/factories/classbased/GroupFactory.php

namespace Factories\ClassBased;


class GroupFactory
{

    // stuff //
    public function facilitatedBy(TeamMember $teamMember)
    {
        $this->facilitator = $teamMember;

        return $this;
    }
```

This is what I have in my test:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;


use XYZ;
use Facades\Factories\ClassBased\GroupFactory;


class ClassBasedGroupFactoryTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase, SetUpRolesAndPermissions, WithFaker;

    public function setUp() : void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->setUpRolesAndPermissions();
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_can_set_the_facilitator()
    {
        $facilitator = $this->createTeamMemberWithRoleOf('facilitator');

        $group = GroupFactory::facilitatedBy($facilitator)->create();

        $this->assertEquals($facilitator->id, $group->facilitator->id);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function another_test()
    {
        $x = 'y';

        $group = GroupFactory::someThing($x)->create();

        $this->assertEquals($x, $group->theThing);
    }
```

And I have this in my `composer.json`:

```
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            // files
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "database/factories/classbased"
        ]
    },
```

I would expect to be able to use the class without issue, as I did when it was in the `App` namespace. But when I refactored to this then the errors started.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Probably it's me but I don't understand what error you get.

Comment: "cannot declare class XXX because the name is already in use"

Comment: What class: GroupFactory class?

Comment: Yeah. Have added the exact error at the top of the question now

Comment: The first test that calls it runs fine, then it fails in the second test

Comment: Please try to run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: I tried that a few times before posting. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Try to use aliasing `use Facades\Factories\ClassBased\GroupFactory as FGroupFactory;` then in line 18, change it to ` $group = FGroupFactory::facilitatedBy($facilitator)->create();` and any other lines that has GroupFactory to FGroupFactory to avoid class name collision.

Comment: Just tried that @jasonwubz, still get the same error.

Comment: Have added into question that I am using setup method. Could that be responsible somehow?

Comment: Hi @forrestedw I'm having the same issue after upgrading to Laravel 6 (with L5.8 it works fine). The first test pass, the others one don't. Have found a solution?

Comment: @EnzoNotario sorry, no. I ended up putting everything under standard App\ namespace. Not my preferred solution, but I was fed up of wasting time on this

Comment: thanks... I'm having a lot of issues because I had everything into modules.. I'm moving everything to "normal" folders but I'm just having a lot of weird issues about "Cannot declare class/interface"... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is not existing anymore, but I'm adding a possible solution for those who might stumble across this thread.

Use a `psr-4` autoloader inside `composer.json` and **put the factories on same level and not in a subdirectory of factories**.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Classbased\\": "database/classbased/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
```

Update your files to reflect the proper namespace and directory structure.

```
<?php // database/classbased/GroupFactory.php
namespace Factories\ClassBased;

class GroupFactory {
```

**Sidenote:** I'm still puzzled why using a subdirectory inside `factories/` was not working for me.